# Removing date from url using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I recently changed the permalink format of my blog so the date is removed:

```
http://site.com/blog/2011/01/post-name
```

is now

```
http://site.com/blog/post-name
```

The problem is the url with date is not redirected to new url. I tried some regular expressions in .htaccess but still get 404. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution was

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /blog/$3
```

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-htaccess-hacks-for-wordpress

Comment: Great. In my case I don't have `/blog/` but first the date with year, month and day. My rule is: `RedirectMatch 301 /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$4`

Comment: Thx a lot goksel, in my case, similar to sarcom, I had to had the day and the subfolder: `RedirectMatch 301 /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /blog/$4`

Comment: Building off of @goksel's answer, on my blog, since the URLs were based on the  root *and* used year/month, when I implemented the original suggestion, my images were messed up since their upload path was getting replaced in addition to the post URL.

This was corrected with a slight modification to only rewrite when matching the full exact string (added ^ to the front of the regex):

    `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$3`

Answer (score 1):

Use this rewrite:

```
RewriteRule  blog/\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*) blog/$1 [R=301, L]
```

---

If your whole Wordpress installation is under the `blog` directory, and that's where the `.htaccess` file is located - use this:

```
RewriteRule  \d{4}/\d{2}/(.*) $1 [R=301, L]
```