# Wordpress 301 Redirect .htaccess borks my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am moving from Wordpress to Statamic. My Statamic site requires a .htaccess file and everything works fine until I try to do the mapping.

My previous URLS were: thedalzells.org/2014/08/post-title and the new ones will be thedalzells.org/blog/post-title.

From [Removing date from url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796877/removing-date-from-url-using-htaccess) I created this:

```
# Turn on the Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# If you're running in a subfolder (like http://example.com/statamic),
# add that here. E.g. /statamic/
RewriteBase /

# Protect your system files from prying eyes
RewriteRule ^(_app) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_config) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_cache) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_content) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_logs) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin/themes/[^/]*/(?:layouts|templates)) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?\.yml$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?\.yaml$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ - [F,L]

# This will prevent all .html files from being accessed.
# You may want to remove this line if you want to serve
# static files outside of Statamic
RewriteRule ^(.*)?\.html$ - [F,L]

# Remove trailing slashes from your URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

# Redirect from old URLS
RewriteRule  /\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*) $1 [R=301, L]

# Remove the index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If I do that, nothing works on my site. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Removed the leading slash and added in the proper target '/blog$1' and all is good.